# Grok pattern to parse the ESC key

Tags: regex, grok, logstash-grok, ansi-escape, fluentd

I was writing a [grok pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to parse the logs in [fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) of [cinder-api](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/cinder/), one line out which is:

```
2015-09-17 17:44:49.663 ^[[00;32mDEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [^[[00;36m-^[[00;32m] ^[[01;35m^[[00;32mAcquired semaphore "singleton_lock"^[[00m ^[[00;33mfrom (pid=30534) lock /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py:198^[[00m
```

The `^[[00;32m` and other such occurrences are [ASCII colour codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), which when printed in a terminal is printed like this:

[image]

I need to parse the line and am able to do it when there are no colour codes using the ([tested](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)) pattern
`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}{NOTSPACE:api}%{SPACE}\[(?:%{DATA:request})\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}`

How do I modify the grok pattern so that I am able to parse the coloured log line?

I have found out the following, if it helps anyone arrive to the solution:

- `^[` is actually the [**ESC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character) key whose octal code is **\033**, hex code is **\x1B**, decimal ASCII code is **27** and is represented by **^[** too.
- There is a [fluentd plugin](http://www.fluentd.org/plugins) named [color-stripper](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/fluent-plugin-color-stripper) that does the same but does not working for me, neither is suitable for my use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution than a literal escape character would be to follow the hints in the links provided:

- [Regular Expressions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_regular_expressions)

  > Grok sits on top of regular expressions, so any regular expressions are valid in grok as well. The regular expression library is Oniguruma, and you can see the full supported regexp syntax [on the Onigiruma site](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE).
- [Oniguruma Regular Expressions: 2. Characters](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE)

    `\t           horizontal tab (0x09)
    \v           vertical tab   (0x0B)
    \n           newline        (0x0A)
    \r           return         (0x0D)
    \b           back space     (0x08)
    \f           form feed      (0x0C)
    \a           bell           (0x07)
    \e           escape         (0x1B)`

Also, color codes can be mixed with other video attributes which do not use two digits.  Quoting from [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_):

`CSI Pm m  Character Attributes (SGR).
            Ps = 0  -> Normal (default).
            Ps = 1  -> Bold.
            Ps = 2  -> Faint, decreased intensity (ISO 6429).
            Ps = 3  -> Italicized (ISO 6429).
            Ps = 4  -> Underlined.
            Ps = 5  -> Blink (appears as Bold).
            Ps = 7  -> Inverse.
            Ps = 8  -> Invisible, i.e., hidden (VT300).
            Ps = 9  -> Crossed-out characters (ISO 6429).
            Ps = 2 1  -> Doubly-underlined (ISO 6429).
            Ps = 2 2  -> Normal (neither bold nor faint).
            Ps = 2 3  -> Not italicized (ISO 6429).
            Ps = 2 4  -> Not underlined.
            Ps = 2 5  -> Steady (not blinking).
            Ps = 2 7  -> Positive (not inverse).`

you might also see those for *normal*, *bold*, *underline* and *reverse*.  Finally, the number of parameters is not limited to two, and parameters are *optional*.  The result might be

```
\e\[(\d*;)*(\d*)m
```

Comment: Looks like the better way to do it. Will try this once that am free of the stuff am working on.

BTW, I am a big fan of your work! Had worked with ncurses a couple of years back, and your name is synonymous to ncurses. Didn't know you were here on stackoverflow! :D

Comment: In my case was showing the character    (x001b), then I put "\e" in to regex and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

The trick was to use the [ESC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) character itself, rather than its representation `^[`.

I use emacs, so I called the function `(insert-char)` and input the hex code of the character `1b` and used that character in the grok pattern.

The grok pattern for ANSI colour codes that I wrote is:

[image: Grok pattern for ANSI colour codes]

instead of

[image: Not the Grok pattern for ANSI colour codes]

Note that `^[` is a single character.